# MySQL JSON data type and JSON_ARRAY_APPEND does not work

Tags: mysql, json

I am struggle with JSON and MySQL.  I am trying to append to a JSON object.

Object has this form:

```
[{},{},...]

SELECT JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(my_meta, '$[0]', '{"private_key": "adfadf"}') 
FROM my_object where user_id='11111'
```

I get the below error using  5.7.8-rc

```
Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION JSON_ARRAY_APPEND does not exist
```

So how do append then given I follow the docs?

Comment: What's your MySQL version? `SELECT VERSION();` **MySQL 5.7.8 supports a native JSON data type**

Comment: I upraged to 5.7.13 but now not inserting but no errors as well